# How to extract all links from a particular page and place them into an array with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, extract

Honestly, I don't know where to start with "extracting." My best guess would be to use the basic .html() tag from JQuery to solve this problem. This is for a small project to improve my JavaScript skills. Any ideas on how this could be done? Thanks so much...

I apologize for being unclear. I meant extracting all the links from a particular page from a domain I don't own. Then, putting these links into an array. Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to put that remote page in a new window then extract the the urls from it and either store it in `localStorage` or a cookie. otherwise you would need to use **ajax** and put the retrieved page in a `input type='hidden'>`

Answer (score 5):

Well, this comes to mind ?

```
var arr = [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('a') );
```

It gets all the matching elements with [**`querySelectorAll`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), and converts the returned nodeList to an array using `[].slice.call`, where `[]` is a shortcut for `Array.prototype`. In other words it calls the native `Array.slice` method with `call()`, passing the elements in as the `this` value, effectively creating an array from the elements.

if you need the HTML, and not the DOM elements, you can map the elements array and return the `outerHTML`

```
var markup = arr.map(function(elem) { return elem.outerHTML; });
```

or if you just need the URL's, you can run the same map and return the `href` attribute instead

```
var urls = arr.map(function(elem) { return elem.getAttribute('href'); });
```

Comment: And if he needs the urls? (Assuming the element has a href) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need jQuery for this and if learning Javascript is your goal you might be better off without using it for now. [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) is available in all modern browsers and can accomplish what you are looking for. Per the documentation:

> Returns a list of the elements within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that match the specified group of selectors. The object returned is a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

A NodeList is not an array however so you would need to do a little extra work to make an array of the link [elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element). You can read in the documentation why they are different.

The selectors used in the method are [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors) and you can checkout the documentation for [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) for examples.

So to do what you want you could do something like:

```
var a_list = document.querySelectorAll('a'); // returns NodeList
var a_array = Array.prototype.slice.call(a_list); // converts NodeList to Array
```

Answer (score 0):

If the jQuery is an acceptable option, you can get all the links by a simple

```
var links = $('a[href]');
```

The "links" is an array already.

Answer (score -1):

I would also fiddle around with something like this.

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'));
```

Googling it would be a good start so you can learn more about how it works and use it to your advantage.